# counting consecutive numbers count in data step in sas

Tags: sas, analytics

I have data set like below.

```
accntid  month  flag  output
123      201501  1     1
123      201502  .     
123      201503  1     2
123      201504  1     2
123      201505  .  
123      201506  1     3
123      201507  1     3
123      201508  1     3
```

I want to calculate the count consecutive flag in output column.
I thought of using retain and lag but could not implement successfully.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please post what you've tried

Answer (score 3):

Use a double DOW loop. The first will count the number of records and the second will output the data.  Use the NOTSORTED option on the BY statement to let SAS define the groups.

```
data want ;
  do until (last.flag);
    set have ;
    by accntid flag notsorted ;
    if flag=1 then output=sum(output,1) ;
  end;
  do until (last.flag);
    set have ;
    by accntid flag notsorted ;
    output;
  end;
run;
```